# Do Views get copied during a build of a DotNetNuke MVC Module based on the DNN project templates

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-module-mvc

I installed the DotNetNuke project templates for v 7,8,9 and added a new C# Compiled Module project. Whilst it seems that if I update the Controllers/Actions and compile then refresh the page I can see that the site is using the latest controller (because it's throwing an exception when I try to pass a different Model into the view).

But, compiling doesn't seem to update the views. The project template folders are placed directly in the DesktopModules/MyModule folder so I would have thought any changes made to a view would automatically be updated in the running site.

I've restarted IIS and it made no difference.

Howcome my views aren't updating?

**Edit:**
I just noticed now that during install DNN copies some of the MVC Module files to DesktopModules\MVC\MyModuleFolder. So the question now is: During development are you supposed to manually copy the view files from your project folder in the DesktopModules\MyModule\Views folder to the DesktopModules\MVC\MyModule\Views folder?

Answer (score 0):

When using my MVC Template, you should use the path

/desktopmodules/mvc/ModuleName

instead of the path that gets used with all the OTHER templates.

/desktopmodules/ModuleName

Once you're using the right path, that should solve the "copy" problem, as nothing will need to be moved.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're suggesting this path should be? I'm using an external DNN MVC Module project which seems to do all the packaging when you build. After installation the DLL is automatically built in the same path as the web project's bin folder because of the configuration of the MVC Module project. But the views aren't copied across. For the moment I've put together a basic batch file to do the copying but I thought perhaps I was missing something in the setup of the module project

Comment: If you are using my DNN MVC module template, you should put the project into /desktopmodules/mvc/MODULENAME when you "create" the project in Visual Studio